# ASP.NET Core/EFCore - System.Linq.Dynamic - select only specified property of navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

im trying to figure out how to SELECT only specific property of navigation property of entity.

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC and EntityFramework Core with System.Linq.Dynamic.Core library. I have to use dynamic linq, because i don't know property names of entity when compiling (it is for grid and i want to use it dynamically).

Entity:

```
public class ActionLog : BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string AffectedUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser AffectedUser { get; set; }

    public int ActionType { get; set; }
    public int Action { get; set; }
    public int LogLevel { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Select in repo:

```
public List<TEntity> FilterForGrid(DataManager dm, params IncludeEntity[] includes)
    {
        var Data = Set.AsQueryable();

        foreach (var join in includes)
        {
                    Data = Data.Include(join.Include);               
        }

        Data = Data.Select<TEntity>("new(it.ID, it.Description, it.DateCreated, it.User.Email)");


        ...


        return Data.ToList();
    }
```

(for test purposes are props which i want select hardcoded)

But, when i try to run FilterForGrid method, it throws an exception:
**System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'**

Message:

> "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: member"

Stack trace:

> "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(MemberInfo member,
>   Expression expression)\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.CreateNewExpression(List`1
>   properties, List`1 expressions, Type newType) in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   1379\r\n   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseNew() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   1317\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   1140\r\n   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()
>   in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   894\r\n   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   889\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   835\r\n   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()
>   in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   804\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseShiftOperator() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   780\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseComparisonOperator() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   639\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAndOrOperator()
>   in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   594\r\n   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseIn() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   514\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseAndOperator() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   497\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseOrOperator() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   482\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseLambdaOperator() in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   452\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseNullCoalescingOperator()
>   in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   439\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.ParseConditionalOperator()
>   in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   422\r\n   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type
>   resultType, Boolean createParameterCtor) in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\ExpressionParser.cs:line
>   369\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(Boolean
>   createParameterCtor, ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type
>   resultType, String expression, Object[] values) in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\DynamicExpressionParser.cs:line
>   107\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.Select[TResult](IQueryable
>   source, String selector, Object[] args) in
>   C:\Users\azureuser\Documents\Github\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\src\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core\DynamicQueryableExtensions.cs:line
>   1033\r\n   at
>   ProjectS.DAL.Repositories.Repository`1.FilterForGrid(DataManager dm,
>   IncludeEntity[] includes) in
>   C:\Users\micha\Source\repos\ProjectS\DAL\Repositories\Repository.cs:line
>   321\r\n   at
>   ProjectS.Core.Services.LogService.FilterForGrid(DataManager dm,
>   IncludeEntity[] joins) in
>   C:\Users\micha\Source\repos\ProjectS\Core\Services\LogService.cs:line
>   136\r\n   at
>   ProjectS.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.LogController.GetActionLogData(DataManager
>   dm) in
>   C:\Users\micha\Source\repos\ProjectS\ProjectS\Areas\Admin\Controllers\LogController.cs:line
>   50\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()"

When i remove "it.User.Email", it works.

When i look into Linq.Dynamic.Core sources - into Tests, they are using it same way and it looks it is working...

What i'm doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Additional info:
Static linq (tested and working):

```
        Data = Data.Select(a => new ActionLog
        {
            ID = a.ID,
            Description = a.Description,
            DateCreated = a.DateCreated,

            User = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Email = a.User.Email,
            }
```

**TEntity** in my test is ActionLog. 
It uses generic repo. Static LINQ tested in specific repo for ActionLog.

Comment: What is `TEntity` in your test? And what property in `TEntity` is supposed to get assigned by `it.User.Email`? Dynamic or not, what it does is LINQ `Select`. In other words, how the static `Select` would look with the same sample?

Comment: TEntity in my test is ActionLog entity.

Comment: And static linq (not sure):             Data = Data.Select(a => new
            {
                ID = a.Id,
                Description = a.Description,
                DateCreated = a.DateCreated,
                User = new
                {
                    Email = a.User.Email
                }
            });

Comment: Tested static linq:             `Data = Data.Select(a => new ActionLog
            {
                ID = a.ID,
                Description = a.Description,
                DateCreated = a.DateCreated,
                User = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Email = a.User.Email
                }
            });`

Comment: I see. AFAIK (in case Core version didn't add something) Dynamic LINQ syntax has no way to express `User = new ApplicationUser { ...}`. The expression `it.User.Email` probably is attempted to be mapped to `Email` property of the `TEntity` class (similar to anonymous types).

Comment: So how to make it dynamically? Yes, i can make it using static linq, with specific repo, but better way for me is dynamic way. Maybe use Linq.Expressions? The problem is, i have no experience with Linq.Expressions and i cant find good documentation, or something...